# Parse JSON Arabic values in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm facing an issue related to parsing Arabic JSON values . It shows like encoded format `\u0637\u0631` etc. The same I had achieved in Android version using **UTF8 conversion**. I m very new to iOS environment. Would appreciate any help related to the same.

**PS:** tried google but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let encodedData = <Your Parse String>.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

If you want to encode the parsed string in `UTF8`, like you are doing for `Android` then the above syntax should work in this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let newChar = "\u{0637}\u{0631}"
```

This should work.

Have a look here

[image]