# swfit 3 when parse json. Some title in arabic the code not run

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I can't run my code within some field in Json file Arabic and Hebrew Language.

> title"يسري "

How to parse Json file with Arabic or Hebrew. I don't have nay idea to parse this type of Json file.

```
//
//  Aqsa.swift
//  yosriiptv
//
//  Created by yosri hadi on 9/16/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Developers Academy. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import Foundation

class Aqsa
{
    var title: String?
    var description: String?
    var thumbnailURL: URL?


    var url: URL?
    var aqsas = [Aqsa]()

    init(title: String, description: String, thumbnailURL: URL, createdAt: String, author: String)
    {
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL
      }

    init(espDictionary: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        self.title = espDictionary["title"] as? String

        // description = espDictionary["description"] as? String
        thumbnailURL = URL(string: espDictionary["thumbnailURL"] as! String)

        self.url = URL(string: espDictionary["link"] as! String)
    }

    static func downloadAllEpisodes(completion: ([Aqsa]) -> ()) {
        var aqsas = [Aqsa]()
        let url = URL(string:"http://pallive.xp3.biz/aqsa.json")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                completion(aqsas)
            }
            else {
                if let jsonData = data ,let jsonDictionary = NetworkService.parseJSONFromData(jsonData) {
                    print(jsonData)
                    let espDictionaries = jsonDictionary["episodes"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]
                   // print(espDictionaries)
                    for espDictionary in espDictionaries {
                        let newEpisode = Aqsa(espDictionary: espDictionary)
                        aqsas.append(newEpisode)
                    }
                }
                completion(aqsas)
                //print(aqsas,"hadi yosri")
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

Any suggestion for this question will be very much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284177/parse-json-arabic-values-in-swift-ios

Comment: man thanks but the the json file have to encoding

Comment: thanks every one
just save json file to encoding utf8